# Is there an elementary proof of a result about the parity of the period of the repeating block in the continued fraction expansion of square roots

Tags: nt.number-theory, continued-fractions

It is a known fact that for a Prime $P$, $P\equiv 1$ mod $4$ iff the length of the period in the repeating block for the continued fraction expansion of $\sqrt{P}$ is odd.  I have an elementary proof of this using the classical result: $P\equiv 1$ mod $4$ iff $x^2-Py^2=-1$ has integer solutions and a proof that $x^2-Py^2=-1$ has integer solutions iff the length of the period in the repeating block for the continued fraction expansion of $\sqrt{P}$ is odd.

I have tried repeatedly to give a direct elementary proof that $P\equiv 1$ mod $4$ implies that the length of the period in the repeating block for the continued fraction expansion of $\sqrt{P}$ is odd, but cant seem to figure it out.  (I have a direct elementary proof of the converse)

Does anyone know of an elementary proof of this result or where I may find one?

Comment: I'd be curious to see the elementary proof that P prime, P = 1 mod 4 implies 
integer solutions to x^2 - P y^2 = -1. (I'm afraid I don't know the answer to 
your question.)

Comment: David, here is a sketch:  Let x + ysqrt(p) > 1 be the least unit greater than 1 with norm 1.  Then x and y have to be positive integers (any unit in Z[sqrt(d)] which is greater than 1 must have positive coeff. wrt the basis {1,sqrt(d)}).  Show x is odd, y is even and from the equation py^2 = (x+1)(x-1) get an equation m^2 - pn^2 = 1 where 1 < m < x.  This can't go on forever, so some unit in Z[sqrt(p)] must have norm -1. 

Comment: An Elementary proof of the converse:  

Let r denote the length of the repeating block in the Continued fraction (CF) for sqrt(P), P Prime.  If r is odd, then by Lagrange sqrt(P)=[a0,a1,a2,...,am,am,...a2,a1,2a0], where the integers a1,a2,...,am,am,...a2,a1,2a0 are repeating.

Then the (m+1)st complete quotient, say A=[am,...,a1,2a0,a1,...,am], which is purely periodic.

But then A=B, where B denotes the CF for A but with the period reversed.  Thus, by Galois' Theorem, AA'=BA'=-1 and A is a reduced Quad. irrational; hence A=(a+sqrt(P))/b, for a,b in Z.

So, AA'=-1 <=> P=a^2+b^2.

Comment: Nice proof KConrad.  If anyone is interested I have a proof of this using Continued Fractions.

Comment: Jason:  I would like very much to see the proof using continued fractions that you refer to.

Answer (score 6):

This doesn't answer your question, but it might gives some intuition as to why this is true. Given the fact that there exists a solution to the equation $x^2-Py^2=-1$ when $P\equiv 1(\mod 4)$, one sees that the matrix 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}x & Py  \\\ y & x\end{pmatrix}
$$
fixes $\pm\sqrt{P}$ (under the action of $PGL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ on $\mathbb{RP}^1=\partial_{\infty} \mathbb{H}^2$). The conjugacy class of a primitive matrix in $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ (which is not reducible or finite order) is determined by the closed geodesic on the modular orbifold that it represents. This in turn is determined by a sequence of triangles which the geodesic crosses in the Farey graph:
[image]
These triangles come in bunches sharing a common vertex, where the number in each bunch corresponds to coefficients of the continued fraction expansion.
The matrix is conjugate to $$\pm \left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & a_1  \\\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0  \\\ a_2 & 1\end{array}\right] \cdots \left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & a_{2n}  \\\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right]$$ if the determinant is 1, and to 
$$\pm \left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & a_1  \\\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0  \\\ a_2 & 1\end{array}\right] \cdots \left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0 \\\ a_{2n-1} & 1\end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1  \\\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right] $$ if the determinant is $-1$.
[image]

[Remark: the labels in this figure don't quite correspond to the matrices - it should be $a_i$'s instead of $\alpha_i$'s, and $\alpha_{\pm}$ should be $\pm\sqrt{P}$]

The number of such factors corresponds precisely to the period of the continued fraction expansion of fixed points of the matrix, since the closed geodesic is asymptotic in $\mathbb{H}^2$ to the geodesic connecting $\infty$ to $\sqrt{P}$, whose Farey sequence gives rise to the continued fraction expansion of $\sqrt{P}$. 
 This number is even if and only if the matrix is orientation preserving, which is if and only if the determinant is 1. So the determinant is $1$ if and only if the continued fraction has even period, and the determinant is $-1$ if and only if the continued fraction has odd period, corresponding to $P\equiv 1(\mod 4)$.

Comment: There is a nice dual picture using Ford circles.  I think if you draw a vertical line from $\pm\sqrt{p}$ to $i\infty$, the Ford circles that it intersects are tangent to the real line at the convergents.

Comment: Nice pictures! I taught an undergraduate number theory course from this point of view (The Farey diagram) last semester, the notes for which are available here:

http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/TN/TNpage.html

See Chapters 1 and 2 in particular. Conway's topographs also form an integral part of the story. (My apologies for the shameless self-promotion!) When I revise the notes I'll have to add the nice fact discussed in the original post above, which was new to me. Thanks to all for the great answers!

Comment: Thank you Agol!  My proof as stated in the question uses only what I learned from reading C.D. Olds' 'Continued Fractions' and Edward J. Barbeau's 'Pell's Equation' and a lot of thinking.  I have virtually no exposure to Faray Diagrams but have a good foundation in modern algebra.   Is there any books at the master's level that you would suggest so that I can understand your answer?

Comment: Oh, Allen Hatcher has some nice info on this.  Thanks Allen.

Comment: @joro: I think the question is for square roots of primes. 

Answer (score 3):

See *Nagell, Introduction to number theory*, Theorem 107. Originally it was proved by Legendre, see *Dickson, L. E. History of the theory of numbers. Vol. II*, p. 365. There are more examples due to Dirichlet, see *Dirichlet's Werke, Bd. 1 (1889)*, pp. 219-236.

An extended bibliography on negative Pell’s equation can be found in *Gerasim, I.-Kh.I.
On the genesis of Redei’s theory of the equation x 2 -Dy 2 =-1. (Russian) Zbl 0731.01014
Istor.-Mat. Issled. 32/33, 199-211 (1990)* (available in electronic form).